# Is it possible to toggle the visibility of the batch console

Tags: batch-file, visibility

I know there are many methods such as VBScript and third-party utilities to hide the batch program window. Is there a way to toggle the visibility on and off?

Comment: you want to be able to toggle

Comment: @NullSoulException - Yes, he even used the word "toggle" in his sentence, so he knows what the term is.

Comment: Using the `ShowWindowAsync` function in user32.dll you can toggle window styles... Not sure how to use VBScript to call that function though.

Comment: @st8z6fr57abe6a8re9uf Does that method of toggling window styles allow complete window removal?

Comment: @Ice, it won't work in VBScript. I think you'll need to run a third-party utility like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#win).